# Why is this animation choppy and sometimes have long delay before it executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This jquery animation is very choppy in firefox and in both firefox and chrome it frequently has a noticeable delay (~1 second) before it actually starts animating (if I put code to write out tot he console when the onclick handler is called, that will show up immeadiately, but the animation call will have a delay). This delay is not every time, but if you click maybe 5-6 times, you'll see it at least once.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Lag</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .base
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 507px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 40px;
            z-index: 0;
        }

        .one
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 2px;
            left: 2px;
            width: 994px;
            height: 34px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: solid 1px #505050;
            z-index: 3;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        }

        .oneA
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 966px;
            height: 6px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #999999;
            border: solid #cccccc 4px;

        }

        .two
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 1px;
            left: 1px;
            width: 996px;
            height: 36px;
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            border: solid 1px #505050;
            z-index: 2;
            opacity: 0.25;
            filter: alpha(opacity=25);
        }

        .three
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 998px;
            height: 38px;
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            border: solid 1px #505050;
            z-index: 1;
            opacity: 0.12;
            filter: alpha(opacity=12);
        }

        .four
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            left: 17px;
            width: 966px;
            height: 6px;
            background-color: #e8e8e8;
            z-index: 0;
            opacity: 0.5;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
        }

        .five
        {
            position: absolute;
            top: 17px;
            left: 17px;
            width: 966px;
            height: 366px;
            z-index: 4;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id ="base" class="base">
        <div id="one" class="one">
        <div id="oneA" class="oneA"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="two" class="two"></div>
        <div id="three" class="three"></div>
        <div id="four" class="four"></div>
        <div id="five" class="five">There's some text in here.</div>
    </div>

    <script>
       var isOn = false;

       var jq_base = $('#base');
       var jq_one = $('#one');
       var jq_oneA = $('#oneA');
       var jq_two = $('#two');
       var jq_three = $('#three');
       var jq_four = $('#four');

       var baseTop = 96;
       var baseStartTop =507;

       var baseHeight = 400;
       var oneHeight = 394;
       var oneAHeight = 366;
       var twoHeight = 396;
       var threeHeight = 398;
       var fourHeight = 366;

       var baseStartH = 40;
       var oneStartH = 34;
       var oneAStartH = 6;
       var twoStartH = 36;
       var threeStartH = 38;
       var fourStartH = 6

       document.onclick = function()
       {
           //It's opened
           if ( isOn )
           {
               jq_one.animate( { height: oneStartH }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
               jq_oneA.animate( { height: oneAStartH }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
               jq_two.animate( { height: twoStartH }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
               jq_three.animate( { height: threeStartH }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
               jq_four.animate( { height: fourStartH }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
               jq_base.animate(
                   { height: baseStartH },
                   {
                       duration: 300,
                       queue: false,
                       step: function (now)
                       {
                           if ( now <= ( baseStartH + 10 ) ) jq_base.animate( { top: baseStartTop }, 800 );
                       }
                   }
               );

               isOn = false;
           }

           //It's closed
           else
           {
               jq_base.animate(
                   { top: baseTop },
                   {
                       duration: 800,
                       step: function (now)
                       {
                           if ( now <= 100 )
                           {
                               jq_base.animate( { height: baseHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                               jq_one.animate( { height: oneHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                               jq_oneA.animate( { height: oneAHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                               jq_two.animate( { height: twoHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                               jq_three.animate( { height: threeHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                               jq_four.animate( { height: fourHeight }, { duration: 300, queue: false } );
                           }
                       }
                   }
               );
               isOn = true;
           }
       }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/fnswz/

Comment: I added a jsfiddle demo for you, and it seems fine to me in Chrome as long as you don't click while the previous animation is still running. (Sorry, I don't have FF on this computer.)

Comment: nnnnnn: what's your computer's specs (RAM, CPU, GPU)? I'm thinking you probably have a very powerful computer. Running the jsFiddle (and clicking multiple times, while waiting for each to end) I still get the issue. And my computer's about avg. (1.8 MHz CPU, 1.5GB RAM, GeForce 8400 GS GPU)

Comment: I'm just using an old laptop at the moment. It has an Intel T2080 CPU, which apparently is 1.73GHz, with 1.37GB RAM. (Are you sure you mean 1.8 **M**Hz and not **G**Hz for your computer?) Anyway, I've posted an answer with what I think is the problem (or at least one problem), with an updated demo that (for me, at least) is a big improvement.

Comment: i have chrome 16 running on a P4 1.8 single core, 1GB RAM and 16MB internal graphics memory. the animation is quite smooth, even for my PC. must be your browser or you should optimize your scripts and do less calls/manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in the following part of the `if (isOn)` branch:

```
  jq_base.animate(
      { height: baseStartH },
      {
          duration: 300,
          queue: false,
          step: function (now)
          {
              if ( now <= ( baseStartH + 10 ) )
                 jq_base.animate( { top: baseStartTop }, 800 );
          }
      }
  );
```

Specifically, within the `step` function of that particular `animate()` call you start another animation with quite a long duration (800ms), and because it is in the `step`, even with the if test you are starting *multiple* animations with that long duration.

That means that although the process reaches a point where it *looks* finished because everything has moved to its final position, behind the scenes these extra animations haven't finished running and so it doesn't respond properly to subsequent clicks. If you move that 800ms animation out of the `step` function and simple put it afterwards it seems to make everything work much more smoothly. (At least, it seems much better in Chrome: as I said in my comment above I don't have FF on this computer so I can't test that.)

Here's a demo with the change I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/fnswz/1/

You may want to set a flag `animationRunning` when you start the animation and then unset it using `animate()`'s `complete` callback, so that you can test the flag and ignore clicks until the current animation has finished, but just the change above made a big improvement for me.

(By the way, why are you using `document.onclick = ...` when you're using jQuery?)

Comment: nnnnnn - I'm not using that in my actual code. I just did that for putting together a quick example showing the issue. It was just a quick slap it together and isolate the problem code type of thing.

Comment: I found the same issue.  This will cause problems, so Don, it needs to be fixed in the example at least.

Comment: I'm all for cut-down examples in SO questions, but in this case I found a specific problem in your code and fixed it such that it seemed to work much better. If you're actually using _different_ code I can't really guess what might be wrong with it - at least I've given you one thing to look into... But your question mentioned a delay in response of about one second, and 800ms is about one second...

Comment: nnnnnn - I understand what your thoughts are with the animation inside an animation but actually that's not where the delay is. The delay is in the other one (called when isOn == false). I've actually found that if I didn't start that animation within the step that there's a lag there, so that code actually eliminates delay. The problem is that it never even gets inside the "step" function of the "isOn == false" animation code when there's a delay for a good 1-2 seconds.

Comment: OK, well based on the code you've given all I can see is what I already mentioned (which for me _definitely_ caused a problem that went away with my suggested change). Maybe you should post a jsfiddle of your own with your _real_ code rather than a cut-down example.